# Any alternative to iOS for an iPhone 3G?

Tags: ios, iphone, unix

I have an iPhone 4, and I would like to recycle my “old” iPhone 3G.

Is there a good Android-for-iPhone?
A Linux distribution optimized for iPhone?
Another alternative OS, like a BSD or a BeOS-like?

What OS other than iOS can run on iPhone 3G hardware and how would I install the OS you recommend.

Comment: Not to mention WebOS :-)

Comment: Oups :-) WebOS would definitely be a good choice too (NodeJS!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can tried iDroid for iPhone 3g. I installed it to my friends iPhone 3G. 
But you need to have jailbroken iPhone. 
Click on the following link: [www.idroidproject.org](http://www.idroidproject.org/)
They are having Bootlace application which will installed the iDroid on your phone. 
the version I used on 3g, was not very impressive(but these guys are continuously working on it to make it better). Recently I got update from that new version is out. 
I personally found it hard daily basis need. but If you are keeping it as experiment its really good. 
Its hard for iPhone to have another software as it need complete reverse engineering[Hard Job] to get some other OS work on it perfectly. 
But still you can give iDroid a try. Its easy to install and remove if you don't like it.

Comment: Your link above doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered looking into Whited00r?

I'm a big fan of the work and you can start at the web page below for details on the hardware it supports:

- http://www.whited00r.com

Once you've jailbroken your device, you can [use iTunes to install this OS](http://www.whited00r.com/installation) on to your iPhone 3.

Comment: I've changed your post to link to the software. It doesn't appear to really be a linux based or any alternate OS and instead seems to be a curated collection of modifications to iOS as well as a replacement for iCloud functionality that is notoriously bad on jailbroken software and hardware.

Comment: I second the recommendation of Whited00r - I use it on a first generation iPod Touch and it makes the device a lot more usable than with unmodified iOS. And yes, it is just a patched version of iOS, not an alternative OS.